# Populating Component 1 of Picker view with respect to selection made in Component 0 of same Picker

Tags: xcode, uipickerview

I am very new o XCode. I was using Picker VIew and got stuck at one place.
I have a Picker View with two Components. And I have three arrays. Array, Array1, Array2.

Now what I want to accomplish is that. When the first object of Array is selected in Component  0, second component gets populated by Array 1.
And when second object is selected from Array in first component. Second Component gets reloaded and gets populated by Array2.

I am very confused on how to accomplish this.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
  {
return [Array count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
         titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
        forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if (component == 0)
return [Array objectAtIndex:row];
else 
    return [[ArraysOFArrays objectAtIndex:row]objectAtIndex:0 ]; 
 //ArraysOFArrays = Array1 & Array2
[technologyPicker reloadComponent:1];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
  inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{   
    if ((component == 0) && (row ==0))
    { 
    if (component == 1)
    {
        [Array1 objectAtIndex:0];

    }
    selectTechnology.text = [technologyData objectAtIndex:row];
   [technologyPicker reloadComponent:1]; 
}

if ((component == 0) && (row ==1))
{ 
    if (component == 1)
    {
    [Array2 objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    [technologyPicker reloadComponent:1]; 
}


}
```

Comment: can you post your. how you are initially populating your pickerview? If possible post all the delegate method implementations of your picker view

Comment: i have added the code. Please look through it.

Comment: i have a solution for you just have a look at it.hope that works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code try this. Take a global variable "selected" of type int and initialize its value to 0 . And BTW what is this "technologyData"?

No of components

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 2;
}
```

No of Rows in component

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
  {
     if (component==0)
         return [Array count];
     else
     {
          if(selected==0)
              [[ArraysOFArrays objectAtIndex:0]count];
          else
              [[ArraysOFArrays objectAtIndex:1]count];   
     }
}
```

title for row

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
         titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
        forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if (component == 0)
    return [Array objectAtIndex:row];
else 
    return [[ArraysOFArrays objectAtIndex:selected]objectAtIndex:row]; 
 //ArraysOFArrays = Array1 & Array2
}
```

did Select row in a component

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
  inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{   
    if (component == 0)
    { 
        if (row == 0)
        {
            selected=0;
            [technologyPicker reloadComponent:1];
        }
        else
        {
             selected=1;
            [technologyPicker reloadComponent:1];
        }
     }
     else
        **selectTechnology.text = [[ArraysOFArrays objectAtIndex:selected]objectAtIndex:row];**

}
```

Comment: Thnx will try this.. TechnologyData is Array i forgot to edit it... Sorry for that...

Comment: What about titleForRow method?

Comment: Just one more thing how to display content of component 2 on label..?

Comment: I have updated my answer look at the last line that is highlighted

Comment: replace the last line with NSLog("%@>>",[[ArraysOFArrays objectAtIndex:selected]objectAtIndex:row]);  and see the log if log is showing the selected row row then there might be some problem in your iboutlet connection for selectedTechlogy label

Comment: Their is no output in Console Window

Comment: Just one more thing. What if the data is dynamic. Its coming from the web service. Then the number of data in array can change. Is their any way to deal with it. Because now we cannot use "if row==0 else row==1".